# Network interface not being found in newer kernel version (ubuntu 20 LTS)

Tags: networking, kernel, internet, interface

The symptom is this, if I pick kernel version 5.4.X I will have a network interface connected to my router (it's on the motherboard), if I pick kernel 5.8.X I will not have a network interface, and no way to connect to my home router.

I was hoping newer versions of the kernel would fix my problem. So far they haven't. And I'm afraid to forcebly be moved into a kernel version where I won't be able to access the internet on this machine.

My motherboard is MSI x470 gaming pro.

Any ideas?

Here's the list of the kernels. Right now only 5.4.0-73 works properly.
[image: photo of available kernels on boot]

On a 5.8.x kernel, the device is not available for the connection (empty device list).
[image: network manager without any devices to add on Ethernet connection]

As per requested I ran the following commands on both kernels:

```
lsmod
sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager

sudo lshw -C network
cat /etc/network/interfaces
cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
dkms status
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version

$ uname -r
5.4.0-73-generic

$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
xt_MASQUERADE          20480  1
nf_conntrack_netlink    45056  0
nfnetlink              16384  2 nf_conntrack_netlink
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_nat                 40960  2 iptable_nat,xt_MASQUERADE
br_netfilter           28672  0
bridge                172032  1 br_netfilter
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
xfrm_user              36864  3
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               491520  2 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
aufs                  262144  0
overlay               114688  0
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
nvidia_uvm           1011712  0
nvidia_drm             57344  9
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
nvidia_modeset       1228800  15 nvidia_drm
snd_hda_codec_realtek   126976  1
nvidia              34131968  732 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          53248  5
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
snd_pcm               106496  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
kvm_amd                98304  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_amd
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 nvidia_drm
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
aesni_intel           372736  0
snd                    90112  20 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
ucsi_ccg               20480  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
wmi_bmof               16384  0
typec_ucsi             40960  1 ucsi_ccg
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
soundcore              16384  1 snd
joydev                 24576  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
input_leds             16384  0
typec                  45056  1 typec_ucsi
ccp                    86016  1 kvm_amd
k10temp                16384  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mac_hid                16384  0
nf_log_ipv6            16384  5
ip6t_REJECT            16384  1
nf_reject_ipv6         20480  1 ip6t_REJECT
xt_hl                  16384  22
ip6t_rt                20480  3
nf_log_ipv4            16384  5
nf_log_common          16384  2 nf_log_ipv4,nf_log_ipv6
ipt_REJECT             16384  1
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT
xt_LOG                 20480  10
xt_limit               16384  13
xt_addrtype            16384  6
xt_tcpudp              20480  26
xt_conntrack           16384  17
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
nf_conntrack          139264  4 xt_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_netlink,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
libcrc32c              16384  2 nf_conntrack,nf_nat
ip6table_filter        16384  1
ip6_tables             32768  53 ip6table_filter
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
iptable_filter         16384  1
bpfilter               32768  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
drm                   491520  12 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
ip_tables              32768  10 iptable_filter,iptable_nat
x_tables               40960  14 ip6table_filter,xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,xt_LOG,xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,ip6t_rt,ip6_tables,ipt_REJECT,ip_tables,xt_limit,xt_hl,xt_MASQUERADE,ip6t_REJECT
autofs4                45056  2
wacom                 118784  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 57344  1 wacom
hid                   131072  3 wacom,usbhid,hid_generic
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
i2c_piix4              28672  0
r8169                  90112  0
i2c_nvidia_gpu         16384  0
ahci                   40960  7
realtek                24576  1
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    32768  1 wmi_bmof
gpio_amdpt             20480  0
gpio_generic           20480  1 gpio_amdpt


$ sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager
-- Logs begin at Sat 2021-03-06 08:37:08 WET, end at Sat 2021-06-05 13:13:33 WEST. --
Jun 05 13:13:12 deepcool systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Jun 05 13:13:12 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895192.8707] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is starting... (for the first time)
Jun 05 13:13:12 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895192.8708] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
Jun 05 13:13:12 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895192.9424] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Jun 05 13:13:12 deepcool systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Jun 05 13:13:12 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895192.9479] manager[0x5653b15a1030]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Jun 05 13:13:12 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895192.9480] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0369] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0369] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "deepcool"
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0371] dns-mgr[0x5653b1589290]: init: dns=default,systemd-resolved rc-manager=symlink
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0374] manager[0x5653b15a1030]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0374] manager[0x5653b15a1030]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0525] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0590] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0641] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0670] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0693] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0695] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0696] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0697] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0698] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0724] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0725] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0725] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <warn>  [1622895193.0727] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0780] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0783] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0796] manager: (enp34s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.0808] device (enp34s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <warn>  [1622895193.2012] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Jun 05 13:13:13 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895193.2041] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Jun 05 13:13:15 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895195.9984] device (enp34s0): carrier: link connected
Jun 05 13:13:15 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895195.9987] device (enp34s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 05 13:13:15 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895195.9993] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (e3fcfb8e-2ae8-3724-b721-c8f972e2f495)
Jun 05 13:13:15 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895195.9996] device (enp34s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (e3fcfb8e-2ae8-3724-b721-c8f972e2f495)
Jun 05 13:13:15 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895195.9997] device (enp34s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.0000] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.0003] device (enp34s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.0007] device (enp34s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.0025] device (enp34s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.0041] device (enp34s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.0042] device (enp34s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.0045] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.0052] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.0052] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp34s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.0127] device (enp34s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.0133] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.0137] manager: startup complete
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.5132] manager: (docker0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.5311] device (docker0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.5334] device (docker0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.5339] device (docker0): Activation: starting connection 'docker0' (727f1da8-abb2-4213-80ae-3f298f2dfb11)
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.5340] device (docker0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.5343] device (docker0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.5345] device (docker0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.5347] device (docker0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.5356] device (docker0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.5357] device (docker0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 05 13:13:16 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895196.5365] device (docker0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 05 13:13:25 deepcool NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1622895205.1462] agent-manager: agent[a669c58d32a27b24,:1.55/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent registered


$ sudo lshw -C network 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:22:00.0
       logical name: enp34s0
       version: 15
       serial: 30:9c:23:b0:82:2a
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.50.250 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:34 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7604000-f7604fff memory:f7600000-f7603fff


$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory

$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

$ dkms status
nvidia, 460.80, 5.4.0-73-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.16, 5.4.0-73-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.16, 5.4.0-74-generic, x86_64: installed


$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1.E0


$ uname -r
5.8.0-55-generic


$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
xt_MASQUERADE          20480  1
nf_conntrack_netlink    49152  0
nfnetlink              16384  2 nf_conntrack_netlink
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_nat                 45056  2 iptable_nat,xt_MASQUERADE
br_netfilter           28672  0
bridge                192512  1 br_netfilter
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
aufs                  258048  0
xfrm_user              36864  3
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
overlay               118784  0
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
nvidia_uvm           1019904  0
nvidia_drm             57344  4
nvidia_modeset       1228800  7 nvidia_drm
nvidia              34140160  287 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
joydev                 24576  0
input_leds             16384  0
kvm_amd                98304  0
kvm                   712704  1 kvm_amd
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           372736  0
drm_kms_helper        217088  1 nvidia_drm
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cec                    53248  1 drm_kms_helper
rc_core                61440  1 cec
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
efi_pstore             16384  0
ccp                    98304  1 kvm_amd
nf_log_ipv6            16384  5
ip6t_REJECT            16384  1
nf_reject_ipv6         20480  1 ip6t_REJECT
xt_hl                  16384  22
ip6t_rt                20480  3
nf_log_ipv4            16384  5
nf_log_common          16384  2 nf_log_ipv4,nf_log_ipv6
ipt_REJECT             16384  1
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT
xt_LOG                 20480  10
xt_limit               16384  13
xt_addrtype            16384  6
xt_tcpudp              20480  26
xt_conntrack           16384  17
nf_conntrack          147456  4 xt_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_netlink,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
libcrc32c              16384  2 nf_conntrack,nf_nat
sch_fq_codel           20480  1
ip6table_filter        16384  1
ip6_tables             32768  53 ip6table_filter
iptable_filter         16384  1
parport_pc             45056  0
bpfilter              884736  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
drm                   552960  7 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
parport                65536  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  10 iptable_filter,iptable_nat
x_tables               49152  14 ip6table_filter,xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,xt_LOG,xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,ip6t_rt,ip6_tables,ipt_REJECT,ip_tables,xt_limit,xt_hl,xt_MASQUERADE,ip6t_REJECT
autofs4                45056  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 57344  0
hid                   135168  2 usbhid,hid_generic
ahci                   40960  7
xhci_pci               20480  0
libahci                36864  1 ahci
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci


$ sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager | cat
-- Logs begin at Sat 2021-03-06 08:37:08 WET, end at Wed 2021-06-09 14:47:30 WEST. --
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.5744] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is starting... (for the first time)
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.5745] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.5869] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.5916] manager[0x55af6d03e030]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.5917] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.6817] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.6817] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "deepcool"
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.6821] dns-mgr[0x55af6d02a290]: init: dns=default,systemd-resolved rc-manager=symlink
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.6824] manager[0x55af6d03e030]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.6824] manager[0x55af6d03e030]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.6968] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7043] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7096] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7116] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7186] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7189] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7190] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7192] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7193] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7249] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7249] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7249] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <warn>  [1623246172.7261] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7348] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7351] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <warn>  [1623246172.7372] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7429] manager: startup complete
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7454] modem-manager: ModemManager not available
Jun 09 14:42:52 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246172.7743] modem-manager: ModemManager now available
Jun 09 14:42:53 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246173.5650] manager: (docker0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Jun 09 14:42:53 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246173.5927] device (docker0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 09 14:42:53 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246173.5951] device (docker0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 09 14:42:53 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246173.5958] device (docker0): Activation: starting connection 'docker0' (4189d399-d415-4aa5-940a-64803ca5a0d6)
Jun 09 14:42:53 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246173.5959] device (docker0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 09 14:42:53 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246173.5963] device (docker0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 09 14:42:53 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246173.5965] device (docker0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 09 14:42:53 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246173.5967] device (docker0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 09 14:42:53 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246173.6041] device (docker0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 09 14:42:53 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246173.6043] device (docker0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 09 14:42:53 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246173.6046] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 09 14:42:53 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246173.6053] device (docker0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 09 14:45:44 deepcool NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1623246344.0928] agent-manager: agent[fcc56abcfe6fea0b,:1.56/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent registered

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:22:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7604000-f7604fff memory:f7600000-f7603fff


$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory

$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

$ dkms status
nvidia, 460.80, 5.4.0-73-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.16, 5.4.0-73-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.16, 5.4.0-74-generic, x86_64: installed

$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1.E0
```

EDIT:

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=default

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

sudo ifconfig enp34s0 up 
enp34s0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Boot the old kernel. `lsmod`, `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Boot the new kernel. `lsmod`, `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Compare.

Comment: Boot to a 5.4.0 kernel, edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `dkms status`. Then boot to a 5.8.0 kernel and show me `sudo lshw -C network` again. Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: edited as per requested, I ran the commands you asked. Notice that I can't see the enp34s0 listed on the newer kernel.

Comment: @heynnema update

Comment: @waltinator update

Comment: Please see my initial answer. Edits forthcoming...

Comment: @fullmooninu Status please...

Comment: @heynnema updated. Where did you see I could get an IP on the newest kernel?

Comment: @fullmooninu I saw the IP in your first `sudo lshw -C network` command, where I guess the card was working for a small period of time. Where are you now? Did the BIOS update, or the other driver, get things going for you? If not, have you re-seated the ethernet card in its slot?

Comment: nope, nothing worked so far. I've noticed something interesting. The network GUI "edit connections menu" (the one in the screenshot) is not shared between the kernel version. So i'm thinking something related to file locations changed between versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ethernet interface, enp34s0, is actually working, and picking up an IP address of 192.168.50.250. However `sudo lshw -C network` shows the device as UNCLAiMED.

**Note**: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

**Note**: Try `sudo ifconfig enp34s0 up`. Report back.

**BIOS**

MSI X470 Gaming Pro

You have BIOS version 1.E0. There's a newer BIOS available, version 7B79v1l3(Beta version), dated 2021-04-26, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/x470-gaming-pro).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Note**: Keep monitoring the web page for newer, non-beta, BIOS updates.

**DRIVER**

Wait with performing this...

Install `r8168-dkms` and see if that helps. If not, remove it.